# For asset uploads, where should the 'temporary path" be created?

Tags: assets, permissions, filesystem

I just moved my Craft CMS site to production (MediaTemple DV) and I can't upload images to my asset sources. I get this error:

`Error uploading the file: there was a problem creating the temporary path.`

I have checked (and fixed) the asset source paths but I still get the error.
I guess I need to change permissions on some directory, but which one? I don't know where this 'temporary path' is supposed to be created.

Have I diagnosed the error correctly? If so, where should that path be created?

Comment: My guess would be permissions if you just pushed to production. Access your server via FTP and navigate to where your assets folder is (presumably in the root directory). Right click on the folder and look for something like "Permissions" or "Info"— somewhere to change the permissions.  Try changing the permissions to that folder to 774.  Also try doing this to each folder inside /assets that you'll be uploading to.

Comment: I'd check the permissions of whatever php.ini https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php is set to and make sure that PHP can write to it.

Comment: In php.ini I uncommented this line (the third one): 
`; Directory where the temporary files should be placed. ; 
; Defaults to the system default (see sys_get_temp_dir) 
sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"`, but so far no change.

Comment: Ryan: I have opened permission to 774 on the asset directories, but I'm pretty sure the temporary file path is not in the asset folders. I'm not completely sure, but I don't think so.